# Inconsistent information from different DMVs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, dmv

I've a server with 12 GB of physical RAM. I just lowered its `'Max Server Memory (MB)'` setting from 10 GB to 8 GB.

If I look at the processes' committed memory in Perfmon, I see:

```
select *
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
where [object_name] like 'SQLServer:Memory Manager%';
go
```

```
Target Server Memory (KB):  8388608
Total Server Memory (KB):   8388608
```

Showing that SQL Server has already relased the additional 2 GB of memory from the Buffer Pool.

However, if I look at the `sys.dm_os_sys_info`:

```
select [bpool_committed]
     , [bpool_commit_target]
     , [bpool_visible]
from sys.dm_os_sys_info;
go
```

I get inconsistent results:

```
bpool_committed     = 1048576
bpool_commit_target = 1048576
bpool_visible       = 1048576
```

Shouldn't `sys.dm_os_sys_info` reflect the information on the performance counters?

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP1 on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: What are the breakdowns for the other counters in the Memory Manager object (e.g. Free Memory, Database Cache Memory, SQL Cache Memory, Optimizer Memory, Log Pool Memory)? If there is some inconsistency here I bet dollars to donuts a service restart will straighten it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values were indeed inconsistent and went back to normal after an instance restart.

I recommend not using the `sys.dm_os_sys_info` for this kind of information since it's not reliable and use the performance counters instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is no inconsistency:

> 1048576 * 8 = 8388608 KB => 8 GB;

Both Perfmon and `sys.dm_os_sys_info` show 8 GB;

`[bpool_visible], [bpool_commit_target] and [bpool_committed]` - in SQL 2005 all these are defined as "Number of 8-KB buffers ..." *(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175048(v=sql.90).aspx)*, so you have to multiply the result by 8 to get KB; Starting with SQL 2008 R2 you no longer have to do the multiplication.

If you want to use a multiplication within the query try:

```
SELECT CAST((bpool_committed * 8) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) AS buffer_pool_committed_memory_in_GB
    , CAST((bpool_commit_target * 8) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) AS buffer_pool_target_memory_in_GB
    , CAST((bpool_visible * 8) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) AS buffer_pool_visible_memory_in_GB 
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;
```